# In Jsoup, how do I parse the CSS query by the attribute, instead of the data?

Tags: java, css, css-selectors, jsoup

In Jsoup when I parse the URL `http://www.singaporepools.com.sg/Lottery?page=wc_four_d` with the CSS Query `option`, I get *"Select a draw date"* for my first element, with the query of `<option selected="selected">`.

In my code, how do I get Jsoup to return that "`<option selected="selected">`", instead of the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
option[selected]
```

It means *"every `option` element that has a `selected` attribute"*.

That should work for you (see example below). Alternatively, if there were more than one `option` with the attribute `selected`, you could specify the attribute value: `option[selected="selected"]`.

**Learn more in [CSS Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).**

Jsoup working example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.singaporepools.com.sg/Lottery?page=wc_four_d").get();
    Elements content = doc.select("option[selected]");
    System.out.println(content);
}
```

Output:

```
<option selected="selected">Select a draw date</option>
```

Comment: "Alternatively, if there were more than one `option` with the attribute `selected`, you could specify the attribute value: `option[selected="selected"]`." If more than one `option` is selected then the first of those will be displayed if it's a non-multiple select. And the value of `selected` is irrelevant, at least in HTML. It would be futile to try and grab elements with only a specific value for it.

Comment: @BoltClock If there is more than one, `doc.select()` will bring them all. But I agree, the value of `selected` shouldn't matter here. My point, along with the CSS Attribute Selectors link, is to explain what that query mean, and that there is more to it than just `element[attribute]`.